# How to create coffeescript singleton subclass

Tags: class, node.js, singleton, coffeescript, extend

I've created a singleton class which I want to extend. It (half) works in that it only creates a single instance of the class, but properties added to the subclass are undefined. Here is the original singleton:

```
class Singleton
   _instance = undefined
   @getInstance: ->
      if _instance is undefined
         console.log 'no instance exists, so create one'
         _instance = new _Singleton()
      else
         console.log 'an instance already exists.'

class _Singleton
   constructor: ->
      console.log 'new singelton'

module.exports = Singleton
```

And here is the subclass:

```
Singleton = require('./singleton')

class Stinky extends Singleton
      constructor: ->
         var1 : 'var1'


module.exports = Stinky
```

Now if I use the following in my node app:

```
Stinky = require './stinky'
thing1 = Stinky.getInstance()
thing2 = Stinky.getInstance()
console.log "Thing var1: #{thing1.var1}"
```

the getInstance() method behaves as expected, but var1 is undefined. If I do this same thing on non singleton classes they work fine. Thanks.

Comment: Is `var1: 'var1'` a typo? Should it be `var1 = 'var1'` or actually `@var1 = 'var1'`?

Answer (score 12):

I trimmed your code down a bit.  Here are the 2 remaining classes:

```
class Singleton
  @_instance: null
  @getInstance: ->
    @_instance or= new @( arguments... )

class Stinky extends Singleton
  constructor: ( @num ) ->

thing1 = Stinky.getInstance( 1 )
thing2 = Stinky.getInstance( 2 )

console.log( thing1.num, thing2.num )
```

I made the following changes:

- Merged Singleton and _Singleton
- Changed _instance to @_instance so that it would be attached to Singleton rather than its prototype
- Added arguments splat in getInstance (in case arguments are needed)
- Pointing getInstance() to extended object rather than Singleton

In this example, I used 2 different numbers to ensure that the 2nd constructor was never called.

Answer (score 2):

I see how you're using the `_Singleton` class to try to simulate a private class, but unfortunately I don't think you can use it in this case.

Here is some code that works:

```
class Singleton
   _instance = undefined

   constructor: ->
      console.log 'new singleton'

   @getInstance: ->
      if _instance is undefined
         console.log 'no instance exists, so create one'
         _instance = new @()
      else
         console.log 'an instance already exists.'
      _instance

class Stinky extends Singleton
      constructor: ->
         console.log 'Stinky constructor'
         @var1 = 'var1'


thing1 = Stinky.getInstance()
thing2 = Stinky.getInstance()

console.log "Thing var1: #{thing1.var1}"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​, thing1, thing2​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I removed the Node.js (require) code, but adding that in should be straightforward. The main difference is that the instance my code is creating is an instance of `@` or `this`. Doing so will make sure your constructor is called first then continue up the parent chain. Your code was explicitly creating an instance of `_Singleton` so your `Stinky` constructor was never being called. Another minor issue that you would have eventually noticed was that your `getInstance` method was not actually returning a instance of `_instance`.

I hope this helps,

Sandro

Comment: Thanks Sandro. Will give it a bash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the goal is, but you can achieve the same result by making `Singleton` a real singleton (a plain object):

```
Singleton =
    doNothing: ->
        # ...
    doMoreNothing: ->
        # ...

class Stinky
    constructor: ->
        @var1: 'var1'
    getInstance: ->
        return Singleton
```

It doesn't make much sense for `Singleton` to have a method that returns itself.

Comment: This is the correct answer for true Coffeescript (and Javascript) style. Javascript is a prototype based language, so common OOP design patterns like the Singleton do not make sense.

Comment: @Vortico I disagree. The fact that CoffeeScript has a `class` keyword tells you that it aims to emulate a more familiar class-based inheritance model. The community-maintained CoffeeScript Cookbook even has a [page on a Singleton pattern](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/chapters/design_patterns/singleton). Sadly, the page doesn't mention inheritance. :(